# Using another congruence criterion as axiom in Hilbert's axiomatic geometry

Tags: reference-request, euclidean-geometry, axioms, plane-geometry, axiomatic-geometry

I have a question about Hilbert's axiomatic system.
In this system we have the SAS (Side-Angle-Side) congruence criterion as an axiom, and then we prove the SSS (Side-Side-Side) and ASA (Angle-Side-Angle) criteria as theorems.
I was wondering then if it was possible to have SSS as an axiom (eventually adding something more) and prove SAS as a theorem, and then again with ASA instead.
I have tried to do some research but I didn't find anything at all. Any reference or result would be welcome, thanks a lot in advance.